# table spacing between lines

Tags: tables

I am having tables with variabes in column A and the results in two lines in column B. However, the numbers are too Close to each other (in my opinion) and it would probably look nicer if there would be some spacing after every second line. Currently it Looks like this:

[image]

But it should somehow look like this:

[image]

Although this does not look much better. What I basically want is some spacing after each parenthesis.

I think an example makes it more clear:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace,geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage[bottom,hang,flushmargin]{footmisc} %footnotes always appear on bottom and not end of text on single page
\geometry{a4paper, top=30mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=30mm,headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Threshold Regression Results}
  \label{tab1:threshold}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{2}{c}}
  \toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Variable} &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Regime 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Regime 2} \\
\midrule
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{x} & -0.962*** & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.39em}}{-2.092***} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & (-5.170) & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.39em}}{(-8.410)} \\
    \multirow{2}[0]{*}{y} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{-0.099} & -0.081 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & (-0.880) & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.39em}}{(-0.320)} \\
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Constant} & 0.696*** & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.39em}}{1.606***} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(-4.710)} & (-9.450) \\
    \midrule
    Threshold variable & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.3245} \\
    Bitcoin($t-1$) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SSR = 2.1297} \\
    \bottomrule

  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents Threshold regression estimation results for x, y and z. Standard deviation in parentheses; *** p < 0.01; ** p < 0.05; * p < 0.10.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the `\addlinespace` command from the `booktabs` package immediately after the corresponding `\\ `  to insert some vertical white space.

Comment: Or `\\[5mm]` or something similar might work as well. Note that both of these solutions are manual, doing this automatically every 2nd line will be more difficult. Could you make the example compilable (add documentclass and packages to the code), so it is easier to try things out?

Comment: Edited the Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with `\addlinespace` after the relevant `\\`. I took the opportunity to add some improvements to your table, with `siunitx`  (alignment of numbers on the decimal dot), `caption` (better spacing between caption and table, adjustable caption font) and `makecell` (common formatting of column heads):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs, makecell, caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
\captionsetup{font=bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
\sisetup{table-format=-1.3, table-number-alignment=center, table-space-text-pre =(, table-space-text-post=$^{***}$, table-align-text-pre=false, table-align-text-post=false}
  \caption{Threshold Regression Results}
  \label{tab1:threshold}
  \begin{threeparttable}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{2}{S}}
  \toprule
    \thead{Variable} & {\thead{Regime 1}} & {\thead{Regime 2}} \\
\midrule
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{x} & -0.962*** & -2.092*** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-5.170{)} & {(}-8.410{)} \\
\addlinespace
    \multirow{2}[0]{*}{y} & -0.099 & -0.081 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-0.880{)} & {(}-0.320{)} \\
\addlinespace
    \multirow{2}[1]{*}{Constant} & 0.696*** & 1.606*** \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & {(}-4.710{)} & {(}-9.450{)} \\
    \midrule
    Threshold variable & \multicolumn{2}{c}{0.3245} \\
   (Bitcoin$_{t-1}$) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{SSR = 2.1297} \\
    \bottomrule

  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[para,flushleft]
  \footnotesize\smallskip
  \item\hspace{-2.5pt}\noindent\textit{Note:} This table presents Threshold regression estimation results for x, y and z. Standard deviation in parentheses; \enspace *** $p < 0.01$; \enspace ** $p < 0.05$;\enspace * $p < 0.10$.
  \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]